# Passport.js - serializeUser doesn't find user properties after lodash _.merge

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, lodash

I have a strange problem with implementing `serializeUser()` on my express app. My data model has called for a single type of "user" to exist in two models, basically an `Identity` (username, password, role, etc) and then role-specific data, such as `Author` (data specific to the Author role). I solve this by having a ref (ObjectID) of an `Identity` stored inside my `Author` model. Thus, my signup function appears as follows (simplified):

```js
// Mongoose will just take what it needs for each model
var identity = new Identity(req.body);
var author = new Author(req.body);

identity.save(function(err) {
    if (!err) {

        // Save reference to identity
        author._identity = identity._id;

        // Save author document, then login
        author.save(function (err) {

            // create new "user" object from both identity and author objects
            var user = _.merge(identity, author);
            req.login(user, function(err) { res.json(user); });
        });
    }
});
```

This is working fine and everything is stored nicely in mongo. However, for `serializeUser()`, I want to store `user._identity`, not `user._id` (or `user.id` as it is strangely used), in order to access the ObjectID of the `Identity` document, not the `Author` document:

```js
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('user', user);           // returns full, concatenated object
    console.log('_id', user._id);          // returns ObjectID value
    console.log('_iden', user._identity);  // returns undefined

    // breaks with a "Failed to serialize user into session" error
    done(null, user._identity);
});
```

What is strange is that `console.log(user)` gives the full (concatenated object), and `user._id` returns a value, but `user._identity` returns `undefined` (and no other value is returned for that matter. Any insight into why this might be happening or a different approach I should take?

NOTE: This seems to be caused by the `_.merge` call. I'm using lodash v.2.4.2

Comment: Can you please post your `user schema`, and also how you are `deserializing` the user.

Comment: Try to output `console.log(user)` just after `_.merge(identity, author);` to see if `indentity` is initialized

Comment: @John `identity` is initialized - what is strange is that only user.id has an assigned value, and not properties from either the `identity` object or the `author` object...

Comment: I prefer to build a json myself. Maybe the merge isn't good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out mongoose doesn't like attempting to `_.merge` two documents - simply using the `document.toObject()` method resolved this issue:

`var user = _.merge(identity.toObject(), author.toObject());`

Not bad at all!